# Is Application Insights on by default for .NET Core services and sites?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

If I build a new .NET Core JSON web service or an MVC web site and host it on premice, would it send any information to Microsoft?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, **it wouldn't send any information** until you add Application Insights to your project.

Comment: Why does my service fail to run without Microsoft.AI.Web.dll in the bin folder? I haven't added anything AppIns related.